# How to allow external access from VisualStudio for private azure devops nuget feeds without providing user credentials

Tags: private-nuget-feed

We have implemented product using several private nugets (Azure DevOps feed) which worked very well.

Now the development is completed and delivered. As part of the agreement, the client wants the source code. When the client tried to compile the source code in VisualStudio, they couldn't restore the nugets as they are in our organization's private feed. Although the PAT is is given in the nuget.config file, the Azure Credential Authentication window asks for the username and password of our organization, which we cannot provide to the client.

Is there any solution for this issue? How usually project code base with private nugets are delivered?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.[image]

We don't want to create a stalkholder user account for anyone in client organization. So the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962115/how-to-allow-external-access-to-a-private-azure-devops-nuget-feed) will not work.

I am thinking of two options:

1. Remove the reference to nuget and add the latest dlls of those libraries directly to the projects
2. Add the private nuget projects into the solution( provide code base for private nugets as well)

Any other way? How can we resolve it using PAT(personal access token)?

Comment: See if the DefaultAzureCredential Class concept can work for you're use case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @mzm, I guess this won't address my issue as Visual Studio is unable to build the solution itself as the nugets (from private feed) don't get restored in the first place!
Thanks anyway.